# What is the best way to handle screenlock and screensaver in Arch/i3?

Tags: i3, screen-lock, screensaver, xset

I recently switched to Manjaro/i3, and I was trying to make i3lock into my screenlock/screensaver, so have it lock the screen after x mn of inactivity, as well as locking the screen upon going to sleep.

I added

> exec xset s 1200 0
>
> exec xss-lock -- i3lock -e -c 333333 &`

to my i3 config in order to have i3lock called after 1200 seconds of inactivity or upon going to sleep, and that seemed to work.

But then I added a module in my i3bar to toggle the 20 minutes feature of the screen lock by `xset s on s 1200 0` to turn it on and `xset s off` to turn it off, and check if it was on by `xset q` and grepping for the timeout value in the Screensaver section of the output, and all of that worked, but it made me realize that xset turns off the screensaver after a random amount of time. I deleted the sections from the i3bar and checked manually with a bash script if the screensaver was on (i.e. `xset q` gave a non 0 value for the timeout in the screensaver section), and it did happen as well, after some time, it's like `xset s off` gets called and the screensaver is off.

Did anyone experience that as well? Before giving xset the screensaver hat, I used xss-lock for locking upon going to sleep, and xautolock for locking after x mn of inactivity, and that worked quite well, except that when I closed the lid with the screen locked, upon waking up I had to unlock twice, which was not very convenient.

I'd be thankful for alternatives as well if you guys use something else! Let me know if there's anything I can share or precise as well.

Florian